# primefaces p:schedule allowparallel events at move event

Tags: primefaces, fullcalendar

I want to be able to drag an event even though there is a parallel event at the same time.
If the start-end period of the events are different then the ui let me move the event. But ifthe two events have a parallel window px first one 10-12 and second one 11-12 then it does not allow me to do the move.
From the back-end code i can do it though

Comment: FYI PF schedule uses FullCalendar

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to go at the backend and at each event to set at `true` the proeprty `OverlapAllowed`.

```
defaultScheduleEvent.setOverlapAllowed(true);
```